# Seleccionar diferentes registros entre tres tablas

Tags: sql, select, join, distinct

Llevo días intentando realizar una consulta que me devuelva los datos diferentes entre tres tablas.

Una tabla `tb_resultados`, otra `tb_met_caract` y otra `tb_valores`, enlazadas las tres por un id.

En la tabla `tb_valores`, registro uno o más valores que puede tener la `tb_met_caract`. En la `tb_resultados`, tantos `met_caract` que tenga una prueba determinada.

Necesito una consulta que me devuelva sólo los datos que están en la `tb_resultados`, con un **join** a las *otras tablas* pero sin repetir la data.

Gracias por cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Acá le dejo una consulta que he intentado, pero me devuelve valores repetidos.

```
SELECT dbo.tb_valores_conform.id_valores_conform
     , dbo.tb_valores_conform.mayor_que
     , dbo.tb_valores_conform.menor_que
     , dbo.tb_valores_conform.mayor_igual_que
     , dbo.tb_valores_conform.menor_igual_que
     , dbo.tb_valores_conform.cumple
     , dbo.tb_valores_conform.sol_esteril
     , dbo.tb_valores_conform.igual_que
     , dbo.tb_valores_conform.id_met_caract_ref_fk
     , dbo.tb_met_caract_ref.id_met_caract_ref
     , dbo.tb_met_caract_ref.id_metodos_fk
     , dbo.tb_met_caract_ref.id_referencias_fk
     , dbo.tb_met_caract_ref.id_caracteristicas_fk
     , dbo.tb_met_caract_ref.especificacion
     , dbo.tb_resultados.id_resultados
     , dbo.tb_resultados.id_caract_met_ref
     , dbo.tb_resultados.resultado
     , dbo.tb_resultados.lote
     , dbo.tb_resultados.fecha_prueba
     , dbo.tb_resultados.respuesta
     , dbo.tb_resultados.id_tipo_product_fk
     , dbo.tb_resultados.id_cerificado_fk
     , dbo.tb_resultados.consecutivo
     , dbo.tb_resultados.id_um_fk
     , dbo.tb_resultados.elaborado_por
     , dbo.tb_resultados.supervisado_por
     , dbo.tb_resultados.observaciones
     , dbo.tb_resultados.result_num
     , dbo.tb_resultados.posicion_esp
       FROM dbo.tb_met_caract_ref
            INNER JOIN dbo.tb_resultados ON dbo.tb_met_caract_ref.id_met_caract_ref = dbo.tb_resultados.id_caract_met_ref
            INNER JOIN dbo.tb_valores_conform ON dbo.tb_met_caract_ref.id_met_caract_ref = dbo.tb_valores_conform.id_met_caract_ref_fk;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si se repiten los datos, es porque tenes relaciones 1Xn o nXm.... cual seria el problema con eso? o usas un distinct, o filtras la consulta para que no pase, o solo traes los campos necesarios... de cualquier manera, necesitariamos saber como se relacionan las tablas, y un ejemplo de datos de entrada y de salida... si queres, usa algun fiddle...

Comment: Si puedes colocas tu BD para que podamos ayudarte mejor